# JS - Exporting object array to an .xlsx file with multiple and merged header rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, typescript, xlsx

I have this excel file that someone created manually that i need to try and recreate programmatically.

I have a node.js(TS) service that exports data into a csv file.
Obviously i can't produce csv files that look like the this.
I need to change the logic a bit and try to produce xlsx file as close as possible to this file:

[image: xlsx file i need to recreate]

I did some looking around and couldn't find anything helpful.
Don't mind the colors, I'm more interested in the rows 1 and 2.

1. Is it possible to do something like that programmatically with Javascript?
2. If the answer is yes, A package name and maybe a short explanation/example will be very helpful.

Thanks!

I gave the XSLX package a try
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)
but didn't even come close to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`exceljs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) library

Demo
I using this excel file.

[image]

Code

```js
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const fs = require('fs');

const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
// input excel file name
const fileName = 'bar-code-data.xlsx';
const csv_fileName = 'result.csv';

// convert index to column name
const columnName = (index) => {
    var cname = String.fromCharCode(65 + ((index - 1) % 26))
    if (index > 26)
        cname = String.fromCharCode(64 + (index - 1) / 26) + cname
    return cname;
}

// apped row into CSV
const appendToCSV = (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16) => {
    const csv = `${c1},${c2},${c3},${c4},${c5},${c6},${c7},${c8},${c9},${c10},${c11},${c12},${c13},${c14},${c15},${c16}\n`;
    try {
        fs.appendFileSync(csv_fileName, csv);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

wb.xlsx.readFile(fileName).then(() => {
    const ws = wb.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    // get merged cells title
    const a1_title = ws.getCell('A1').value
    const d1_title = ws.getCell('D1').value
    const h1_title = ws.getCell('H1').value
    const m1_title = ws.getCell('M1').value

    // set row loop count variables
    const headerColumn = 1
    const start_row = 3
    const how_many_rows = 2

    // reading excel cell data
    for (let row_number = start_row; row_number < start_row + how_many_rows; row_number++) {
        if (row_number == start_row) {
            // reading sub titles
            const a1_sub_title1 = a1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const a1_sub_title2 = a1_title + ' ' +  ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 1) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const a1_sub_title3 = a1_title + ' ' +  ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 2) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const a1_sub_title4 = a1_title + ' ' +  ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 3) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")

            const d1_sub_title1 = d1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 4) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const d1_sub_title2 = d1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 5) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const d1_sub_title3 = d1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 6) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")

            const h1_sub_title1 = h1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 7) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const h1_sub_title2 = h1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 8) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const h1_sub_title3 = h1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 9) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const h1_sub_title4 = h1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 10) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const h1_sub_title5 = h1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 11) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")

            const m1_sub_title1 = m1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 12) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const m1_sub_title2 = m1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 13) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const m1_sub_title3 = m1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 14) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            const m1_sub_title4 = m1_title + ' ' + ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 15) + String(row_number - 1)).value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
            // save header title
            appendToCSV(a1_sub_title1, a1_sub_title1, a1_sub_title3, a1_sub_title4,
                d1_sub_title1, d1_sub_title2, d1_sub_title3,
                h1_sub_title1, h1_sub_title2, h1_sub_title3, h1_sub_title4, h1_sub_title5,
                m1_sub_title1, m1_sub_title2, m1_sub_title3, m1_sub_title4)
        }

        const barcode = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn) + String(row_number)).value
        const ppid = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 1) + String(row_number)).value
        const site = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 2) + String(row_number)).value

        const s1_tube_type = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 3) + String(row_number)).value
        const s1_within_window = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 4) + String(row_number)).value
        const s1_initial_quantity = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 5) + String(row_number)).value
        const s1_temperature_deviation = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 6) + String(row_number)).value

        const sp1_tube_type = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 7) + String(row_number)).value
        const sp1_initial_quantity = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 8) + String(row_number)).value
        const sp1_qc_status = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 9) + String(row_number)).value
        const sp1_pre_qc_check1 = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 10) + String(row_number)).value
        const sp1_pre_qc_check2 = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 11) + String(row_number)).value

        const s2_tube_type = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 12) + String(row_number)).value
        const s2_within_window = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 13) + String(row_number)).value
        const s2_initial_quantity = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 14) + String(row_number)).value
        const s2_temperature_deviation = ws.getCell(columnName(headerColumn + 15) + String(row_number)).value

        // save data row
        appendToCSV((barcode === null)? '' : barcode,
            (ppid === null)? '' : ppid,
            (site === null)? '' : site,
            (s1_tube_type === null)? '' : s1_tube_type,
            (s1_within_window === null)? '' : s1_within_window,
            (s1_initial_quantity === null)? '' : s1_initial_quantity,
            (s1_temperature_deviation === null)? '' : s1_temperature_deviation,
            (sp1_tube_type === null)? '' : sp1_tube_type,
            (sp1_initial_quantity === null)? '' : sp1_initial_quantity,
            (sp1_qc_status === null)? '' : sp1_qc_status,
            (sp1_pre_qc_check1 === null)? '' : sp1_pre_qc_check1,
            (sp1_pre_qc_check2 === null)? '' : sp1_pre_qc_check2,
            (s2_tube_type === null)? '' : s2_tube_type,
            (s2_within_window === null)? '' : s2_within_window,
            (s2_initial_quantity === null)? '' : s2_initial_quantity,
            (s2_temperature_deviation === null)? '' : s2_temperature_deviation)
    }

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Result
[image]

Tips

#1 This code replace multiple lines header into single line header

```
replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
```

#2 `columnName` function : convert column name by number

```
columnName(1) -> A
columnName(2) -> B
```

#3 Null check
if value is null, replace blank character

```
(value === null)? '' : value
```

#4 append row
the `csv` string will append into CSV file

```
fs.appendFileSync(csv_fileName, csv);
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the detailed answer.
I was diverted to some other assignments, I'll let you know as soon as I'm back at it.

Comment: OK, let me know it is address your looking for it or not.